# alternative text not removing

Tags: vba, powerpoint, mschart

I am trying to create an effect so that when I roll over a bar graph, the bar is highlighted and the data point is displayed via alternative text. I do this by overlaying a shape directly over each bar and using a mouseover event to run the following module. The problem is that the module works just fine when I don't try to remove the alternative text on the "reset." When I try to remove the alternative text on the reset, none of the reset code works, and the shapes maintain transparency = 0. I have the code for the alt.text removal portion of the module commented out. Any thoughts on why this may be? I've used very similar code for another project and it worked just fine... it's a mystery! Thanks in advance!

```
Sub highlight (sh As shape)
    If Not sh.Name = "reset" Then
        Set sl = sh.Parent
        Dim shp As shape
        With sh
            .Fill.Transparency = 0
        End With
        For Each shp In sl.Shapes
            If shp.Name = sh.Name Then
                With shp
                    .Fill.Transparency = 0
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shp.AlternativeText
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(250, 250, 250)
                End With
            End If
        Next shp
    ElseIf sh.Name = "reset" Then
        Set sld = sh.Parent
        Dim shpe As shape
        For Each shpe In sld.Shapes
            If Not shpe.Name = "reset" Then
                With shpe
                    .Fill.Transparency = 1
                    '.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ""
                End With
            End If
        Next shpe
    End If
End Sub
```